# Shopping Cart $_GET problem can't work with the id

Tags: php, get, cart

I have a problem with $_GET.

On my index.php file I have a little shopping site where I can buy random stuff by clicking the "buy" button. After clicking the "buy" button I am trying to get the id of the clicked product like this:

```
//Stuff like connection, sql, etc..

$response="";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        //Other Stuff...
        $response .= "<a href='addtocart.php?id=". $row['ProduktID'] . "'><button class='inCart'>Buy</button></a>";
    }
```

And then I have a new file called addtocart.php. I can see the id's:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5DOf.png)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHDLg.png)

addtocart.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(isset($_GET['ProduktID']) && !empty($_GET['ProduktID'])){
     //Do Stuff
  }
  else{
     echo "Error, can't add the item";
  }
```

I am always getting the Error message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `addtocart.php?id` you have used `id`, so in URL it will passed param as `id`

```
     $response .= "<a href='addtocart.php?id=". $row['ProduktID'] . "'><button class='inCart'>Buy</button></a>";
```

**addtocart.php:**

so in php you should access as `$_GET['id']`

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
     //Do Stuff
  }
  else{
     echo "Error, can't add the item";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. there it is.. omg I can't believe it I am so blind..